# How to install suggested packages in apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation

I know the question has been asked before, but please hear me out. So I wanted to install screenlets. I ran `sudo apt-get install screenlets`, and this is what I got:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libgnome2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libtidy-0.99-0 python-beautifulsoup python-evolution
  python-feedparser python-gmenu python-gnome2 python-numpy python-pyorbit python-rsvg python-tz python-utidylib
  screenlets-pack-basic
Suggested packages:
  libbonobo2-bin python-gnome2-doc python-numpy-doc python-numpy-dbg python-nose python-dev gfortran
  python-pyorbit-dbg screenlets-pack-all python-dcop
Recommended packages:
  python-numeric python-gnome2-extras
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libgnome2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libtidy-0.99-0 python-beautifulsoup python-evolution
  python-feedparser python-gmenu python-gnome2 python-numpy python-pyorbit python-rsvg python-tz python-utidylib
  screenlets screenlets-pack-basic
0 upgraded, 23 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

People say that Recommended packages are installed by default, but they are clearly not included in the NEW packages that will be installed above. I also decided to include the Suggested packages in the installation, so I ran `sudo apt-get --install-suggests install screenlets` instead, but I got a HUGE list of NEW packages that will be installed; that number is precisely `0 upgraded, 944 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded`. Should'nt I be getting only around 10 extra packages?

Comment: --install-suggests will be recursive, meaning that it will also calculate suggestions from all the packages suggested by screenlets. That's why you get so many. FWIW I also get like 700 packages to install if I use --install-suggests

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarifying that. That was my initial thought, although I thought it would be ridiculous if it were true.

Comment: Is there a way then to simply install thge suggested packages for the programme/package currently being installed? So, without the recursion?

Comment: In case you used `--no-install-recommends` you can use `apt-get -o apt::install-recommends=true` to install those this time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found out why the *recommended* packages in my question were not included in the packages to be installed. It's because those recommended packages do not exist in the repositories. I tried to install a random package, I chose `sudo apt-get install googleearth-package`. It did not show the **Recommended packages** section (which means they are already included in the NEW packages to be installed section). To confirm this, I ran `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install googleearth-package`, and surely enough the **Recommended packages** section revealed itself. As for the *suggested* packages, I guess I won't be using `--install-suggests` because that just installs the suggested packages and their suggested packages.

Answer (score 95):

*suggests* and *recommends* are not the same thing.

> Package A **depends** on Package B if B absolutely must be installed in order to run A. In some cases, A depends not only on B, but on a version of B. In this case, the version dependency is usually a lower limit, in the sense that A depends on any version of B more recent than some specified version.
>
> Package A **recommends** Package B, if the package maintainer judges that most users would not want A without also having the functionality provided by B.
>
> Package A **suggests** Package B if B contains files that are related to (and usually enhance) the functionality of A.

See [The Debian GNU/Linux FAQ](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html#depends) for details.

By default, `apt-get` installs recommended packages.

Your option `--install-suggests` adds in the suggested packages and their suggested dependencies.

```
--install-suggests
    Consider suggested packages as a dependency for installing.
    Configuration Item: APT::Install-Suggests.
```

see [`apt-get`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/apt-get.8.html).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that dependencies, recommended and suggested packages are not the same thing. However, you say recommended packages are installed by default, but from the extract I posted, the Recommended packages are not part of the "following NEW packages will be installed" list. Furthermore, I actually just installed screenlets and the Recommended packages were not installed =/.

Comment: However, thanks for clarifying the --install-suggests part, although I think it's ridiculous that Ubuntu installs the suggested packages AND their suggested dependencies LOL...the required packages went from 6MB to over 1GB with the --install-suggests option.

Comment: If you found a problem, you should file a bug report. Hard to know but my guess would be it is a problem with packaging and the way dependencies are listed. It may also be that those recommended packages are from the dependencies, not the packages you installed. Again a question of recursive.

Comment: I found out why the recommended packages were not included in the packages to be installed. It's because the recommended packages do not exist in the repositories =/.

Comment: @Alaa Ali - indeed, I tried to install wine and found that with --install-suggests it wound up trying to install emacs packages. Because we all know that there's no reason in running Windows programs if you're a vim user. A slippery slope encountered in the wild!

Comment: Any way to install suggested packages by default?

Comment: What if you want to install the suggested packages *after* the package has already been installed? (`apt-get install <package>` does nothing if the newest version of package is already installed.)

Comment: @JamesHirschorn shout be `sudo apt-get install --install-suggests <package>`

Comment: @Panther yes, thanks that is what I actually meant. But your command does nothing if `<package>` is already installed, even if the suggested packages are not.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn - Can you start a new question with more details. Which package? What are the suggested packages, etc. I think you will get more help that way rather than the comments here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `--install-suggests`. But as it's written in the comments I also find this option unusable because of its recursive behaviour, it pulls enormous amount of dependancies your never want.

I always want the suggested packages of the given package, and NOT the suggested packages of any package to be installed.

You can see suggested packages of the given package(s) like this:

```
apt show PACKAGE 2>&1 | grep ^Suggests:
```

This command allows you to install package(s) with suggests of only given package(s):

```
apt show PACKAGES 2>&1 | sed -nr '/^(Suggests|Package): /{s///;s/( \|[^,]+)?,//g;p}' | xargs apt -y install
```

NOTE: If package suggests a couple of alternatives like `pkg1 | pkg2` it always choses the first.